# scan in arabic characters netbeans 8

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, arabic, netbeans-8

I have this simple code that prints Arabic sentence and scan arabic characters .

what is drivingme crazy is that it prints in cmd right , but never scan characters it scans arabic characters in form of

> ��� �����

I tried everything:  `Scanner(System.in,"UTF-8")`, `Scanner(System.in,"UTF8");`

please help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


     Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in,"UTF-8");

    System.out.printf("  ادخل جملة السؤال \n");
    String s = in2.nextLine();
       System.out.printf(""+s+"");

    // TODO code application logic here
} Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in,"UTF-8");

    System.out.printf("  ادخل جملة السؤال \n");
    String s = in2.nextLine();
       System.out.printf(""+s+"");
```

output :

> ادخل جملة السؤال  هذا تلميذ ��� �����
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)

Answer (score 4):

i have the same problem with netbeans 8 and windows 7
to fix this please do that
open

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0\etc\netbeans.conf
```

you will find this

```
netbeans_default_options="..."
```

add this code at the begining of it so at the end it will look like that

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -J-client ..."
```

and restart the netbeans

check this screen shot 
[image]

Comment: Thank you it worked for me, I am using windows 7 and Netbeans 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about that, it is the IDE's problem. Most IDEs console window don't support other that ASCII, but In real life Swing, this will appear as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in Windows Server 2016.

Solution:
1.  Go to Control Panel -> Region.
2.  Open Administrative tab.
3.  Click “Change System Local” to Arabic.
4.  Restart the server.