# How to Allow netbeans read arabic characters

Tags: php, netbeans, character, arabic

I'm working on netbeans and when I open file that have arabic characters netbeans can't read it

Are there any plugins or a way to read arabic characters ?

Comment: Might be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/29813557/1531192

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29813557/4725998) answer on a similar question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scan in arabic characters netbeans 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076145/scan-in-arabic-characters-netbeans-8)